# Best Practices for making client model classes relatively independent of server

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, client-server

In order make my client model less dependent on the server response, I have to maintain two Model structure, one the client model that the controllers on the client use  and the other one the transport model(or the server model) which is used to map the server response. Then I map my transport model to client model in a mapper class, so that I don't have to make changes in my controllers. But this seem to be too much overkill if I have large number of model classes.

One other approach I tried was having interfaces for the client models with getters and setters to be used in controller, and the implementation of the interfaces for mapping server response. However, it cause lots of customization in `GSON` or `Jackson` mappers. Also, it's not best suited if many classes implement the interface, somewhat defeating the purpose.

So, what are some  good design patterns for maintaining client model relatively independent of server model??

It would be better if answer is provided in context of `Java` and  `Android.`

Answer (score 0):

If you find you are making too many classes, then perhaps what you need instead is just a simple key/value store?